# Why Nami calls him Sanji-kun?

Tags: one-piece

Since both officially joined the crew (by this, I mean after Arlong Park), they use special suffix when talking to each other. In case of Sanji, this is not surprising as he does the same with every girl he meets (as far as I noticed).

Nami, on the other hand, rarely uses such suffixes, with Sanji being the only none she calls Sanji *-kun*.

Is there any canonical reason for this?

Comment: cuz he's a womanizer

Comment: could you specify where, because i'm pretty sure, she doesn't do it all the time, only when they're relaxing.

Comment: As far as i know she only does that when she wants something from him

Comment: I'm pretty sure she does in 90% of the time. In the anime at least.

Comment: I thought she did it to flirt with/manipulate him

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Kun (君【くん】?) is used by people of senior status addressing or referring to those of junior status, by anyone addressing or referring to male children or male teenagers, or among male friends. It can be used by males or females when addressing a male who they are emotionally attached to or have known for a long time.

My guess is she's just being playful.